# custom post-type query just returns two posts

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, query

I'm making a custom activity calendar for a client here: http://arbeidshesten.com/aktivitetskalender/

The backend is a custom post type "aktiviteter", with custom fields for the date ("dato") and some more details.

The code looks like this:

```
<table>

<tr>
<th>Aktivitet</th>
<th>Sted</th>
<th>Dato</th>
<th>kontaktperson</th>
</tr>


 <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type' => 'aktiviteter', 
'meta_key' => 'dato',
'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
'meta_compare' => '>=',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php $display_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, "dato", true))); ?>

<tr>   
<td><?php the_title( '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a>' ); ?></td>
<td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "sted", true); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $display_date; ?></td>
<td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "kontaktperson", true); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</table>
```

Funny thing is that the query returns just 2 aktivities, even though I entered (and published) about 5 future activities.

Anyone a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if adding `'posts_per_page' => XXX` to your query would give the desired results? Just a thought. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that if you are running WP 3.1, the `meta_key`, `meta_value`, and `meta_compare` parameters of the WP_Query is deprecated. In 3.1 and above, the `meta_query` parameter is what you should use. This is an awesome addition to WP_Query as it allows for query multiple meta values. Your query should look like:

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'post_type' => 'aktiviteter', 
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'key' => 'dato',
                    'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                ),
            'orderby' => 'dato',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ) 
    ); 
?>
```

Source:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters